# Removing HTML Table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following code which is supposed to populate a table with artists from a database as soon as the page loads (that works fine). Then when an artist is searched for it should show artists that matched or if there weren't any then it shows "No artists were found!" (that works fine). The issue is that it puts the new table or message next to the original table so I added some JavaScript to remove the original table before the PHP echos the new table or message, that's the bit that doesn't work.

```
<table id="artistTable">

<!-- PHP to display default table of all artists -->

<?php
include 'connection.php';

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM artist");
if(!$stmt)
    {
        echo "Error creating SQL statement";
        return 1;
    }

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($artID, $artName);

echo "<tr>\n
        <th>Artist ID:</th>\n
        <th>Artist Name:</th>\n
        <th>Options:</th>\n
        </tr>\n";

while($stmt->fetch())
{
    echo "<tr>\n
            <td>" . htmlspecialchars($artID) . "</td>\n
            <td>" . htmlspecialchars($artName) . "</td>\n
            <td><a href=\"\">Edit</a> - <a href=\"\">Albums</a></td>\n
            </tr>\n";
}
?>

<!-- PHP to display table after search -->
<?php
include 'connection.php';

if(isset($_GET["artists"]))
{
    /* JavaScript to remove original table */
    echo "<script>
            var table = Document.getElementByID(\"artistTable\");
            table.parentNode.removeChild;
            </script>";

    $artist = htmlspecialchars($_GET["artists"]);

    /* Add wildcards to $artist */
    $artist = "%$artist%";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM artist WHERE (artName LIKE ?)");
    if(!$stmt)
    {
        echo "Error creating SQL statement";
        return 1;
    }

    $stmt->bind_param('s', $artist);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($artID, $artName);

    if($stmt->fetch())
    {
        echo "<tr>\n
                <th>Artist ID:</th>\n
                <th>Artist Name:</th>\n
                <th>Options:</th>\n
                </tr>\n";

        while($stmt->fetch())
        {
            echo "<tr>\n
                    <td>" . htmlspecialchars($artID) . "</td>\n
                    <td>" . htmlspecialchars($artName) . "</td>\n
                    <td><a href=\"\">Edit</a> - <a href=\"\">Albums</a></td>\n
                    </tr>\n";
        }
    }
    else
        echo "<p>No artists were found!</p>\n";
}
?>

</table>
```

Comment: i see no reason for js, your doing a page reload, just dont display the table (via php)

Comment: Just put your default table in a `else{}` of your `if(isset($_GET["artists"]))`

Comment: @Dagon Ah thanks I didn't realise that the page reloaded when there was a search.

Answer (score 0):

try this $('#artistTable tbody').remove();
then
$('#artistTable tbody').html('new table content');